# Problem with assigning delegates in for-loop

Tags: c#, delegates, closures, event-handling

I have an application that is capable of plugins (MEF).
The plugins are WPF UserControls that import services.

The user can select the wanted plugin from the main menu of the application.

To do this, i use the following loop:

```
foreach(IToolPlugin Plugin in ToolPlugins)
{
    Plugin.Init();
    MenuItem PluginMenuItem = Plugin.MenuItem; //New MenuItem but with Header set.
    PluginMenuItem.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(delegate(object o, RoutedEventArgs e) { DoSomething(Plugin.Control);});
    PluginsMenu.Items.add(PluginMenuItem);
}
```

That works very fine for a single item. But as soon as i have more than 1 plugin, all menuitems execute the delegate of the last loop. Or at least with the Plugin.Control of the last loop.

How can i fix this?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I love seeing the many variations of this question.

Comment: @Chaos - in that case you should vote to close ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On each iteration of the loop, you have to "capture" the value of the iterated value before you use it in a closure. Otherwise Plugin in each delegate will point to the last value of Plugin instead of the value that it held when the anonymous function was created.

You can read a more in depth explanation from Eric Lippert here:

[Closing over the loop variable considered harmful - Fabulous Adventures in Coding](https://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/)

In short, the correct way to write your foreach loop is:

```
foreach(IToolPlugin Plugin in ToolPlugins)
{
    Plugin.Init();
    MenuItem PluginMenuItem = Plugin.MenuItem;

    IToolPlugin capturedPlugin = Plugin;

    PluginMenuItem.Click += 
        new RoutedEventHandler(delegate(object o, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            DoSomething(capturedPlugin.Control);
        });

    PluginsMenu.Items.add(PluginMenuItem);
}
```

Comment: I assume you're going to include the obligatory link to Eric's blog posts on the matter? (Closing over the loop variable considered harmful.)

Comment: We should have a rota for this question :) (As it's hard to search for, I don't think it's worth closing it as a duplicate.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet - It's hard to say. I just did a quick search for c# closure foreach and got a tons of hits (also added the closure tag to the question). I think that part of the problem is that people don't realize that these are closures.

Comment: Absolutely. If you know it's a closure, you're half way there.